# Bean Annotation to override XML definition - Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My spring-boot application has another library project included as a dependency. This library project has a spring.xml file where a number of beans defined. One of these beans has another external dependency injected which I don't need in my project. Hence this is throwing an error when I start my application. I want to define the same bean in my application as a java config and make spring-boot ignore the specific bean from spring.xml file. However I want all the other beans in spring.xml to be read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a bean in your local java config with the same name and type as the one inherited in the spring.xml file.

Annotate your bean with [@Primary](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html) which will make yours used over the imported one.

Your application will still use the definitions of all the other beans you inherit.

To prevent other defined beans loading that you do not actually need you have to change the bean creation to [lazy](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Lazy.html) configuration, that is, they only get created when explicitly used.

To do this in your main Spring boot class where the application is created, most likely annotated with `@SpringBootApplication/ @Configuration/ @EnableAutoConfiguration/ @ComponentScan` you should add `@Lazy` above it.

Usually you would explicitly annotate the Bean in question but here it cannot be done as it is originating in a spring.xml file in a 3rd party jar. The idea here is to cleanly state all beans are lazy from the highest point in the spring configuration.

Comment: Thanks @UserF40. In my case , the bean defined in spring.xml is invalid as it is looking for a dependency which I have not injected. I see this error while starting up "Invalid bean definition with name 'dbConfigurationManager'"

Comment: Sure  , will do !! But is it possible to let me know if there is a way to get around the scenario that I had explained in my question.

Comment: This solution does that, all beans from the spring.xml file will be read except the one you define as primary in your own config.

Comment: The bean in spring.xml is throwing an error because one of the dependencies is not injected. I would that bean to be ignored while loading the beans. I thought defining a bean as annotation will help me get around it.Sorry , I did phrase the subject appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to include spring.xml from other jar and exclude a bean in the xml.
I don't know spring framework provides some way.
I prefer to copy the spring.xml file to new project and remove the unnecessary bean.